# Non muslim food business serving Halal food, DO I NEED A CERTIFICATE?

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim, food

I am a Non muslim (Christian) that lives in a very diverse part of london UK. I have always only bought Halal meat from my local Halal butcher, I recently opened a small community cafe, and have choosen to continue to only buy my meat produce from my local Halal butchers, and am very considerate and respectful of other religions and beliefs, and respect all my customers equally. Since opening my cafe I have made sure I have seperated all cooking utensils, halal, vegertarian, and allergen etc. 
I would like to know if this method is considered Halal, or if I need a certifcate to confirm that the food served in my cafe is Halal. 
Thank you for your advise

Comment: Welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and our model consider taking the [tour] and checking our  [help]. I'm a bit curious where or how will you get the certificate? IMO this is a quite opinion based matter: As whether one trusts you when you say the food or meat is halal or not is opinion-based. In Islam there's no such thing as halal-certificate and knowing by experience that al-Azhar would put it stamp on anything when it is well paid I don't see how a certificate would change this by any means, as the matter is a matter of trust.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Islamic religious law does not require a certificate.

However in practical terms, your customers might need you to be certified, they might not take your word for it or they might doubt that you properly know and understand all halal requirements.